# Excel 2013 PowerPivot add-in crashes Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, crash, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

Running into a serious problem with little help on solving the issue. Any time I try doing anything with DAX or sometimes just opening Excel application, Excel crashes and gives me the following errors:

Please HELP!

Error #1

```
Excel is running into problems with the 'microsoft office powerpivot for excel 2013' add-in.   
If this keeps happening, disable this add-in and check for available updates. Do you want to 
disable it now?
```

Error #2

```
We couldn't load the PowerPivot add-in. First try Office Repair to fix issue. The error below 
should help if that doesn't work.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel,
Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral,
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c; or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Things I've tried:

-Office Repair; Quick and Online

-'Fix It' application; re-install Office 365 ProPlus Renaming OS.DLL to OS.DLL.Old; Restarting application

-Restart computer

-Renaming OS.DLL to OS.DLL.Old; Restarting application

Answer (score 1):

After many failed attempts repairing the issue, I finally figured out something that works.

1. Start Excel in Safe Mode ( run: excel \safemode)
2. Alt - F11 (opens VBA editor)
3. Tools > references
4. Un-checked the following:

   - OLE Automation
   - Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
5. 'Save As'
6. Re-open workbook normal

I've not had the errors reappear. Thoughts are that the workbook was corrupted and the add-in was affected.

source: [Excel addins troubleshoot](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552349/Excelplusaddinsplustroubleshootingplusguide)

Answer (score 0):

Start Excel without Add-ins by following these steps here: http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/windows_user/f1087.shtml

After that, start Excel > File > Options > Add-ins

In the Manage box, click COM Add-ins> Go and then you can either disable or remove this Microsoft Office PowerPivot Add-in.

Comment: Answers that depend on links become less useful if that link stops working. A good way to handle it is to quote or restate the relevant portions of the linked article.

Comment: I really need the add-in. Any thoughts on how to repair the add-in. It is part of excel 2013 (office 365 subscription).